# How to rollback to a previous commit in Git?

Tags: git, workflow

I am a newbie to Git.  That being said, I do the most basic things of Git, edit-> stage -> commit routine on my files.  But I actually don't understand the purpose of doing that.  For example, to rollback to a previous commit is quite complicated.  If I check out a previous version, I end up with a detached HEAD, and I lose all the commits after that.  The time line is kind of messed up.

Am I not understanding the concept of Git right?  What should be the correct way of using Git for my work?  I have some simple programs I need to keep track of, and a document (a .tex file) and I keep adding new things to.  I would like to be able to check previous commits from time to time and rollback to an earlier version if needed.

Comment: You need a "basic instructions on Git" book/document. When just *looking at* older versions of Git, you do indeed get this "detached HEAD" thing, but later versions are not *gone*, they're just not shown *by default*. Use `git log <branch-name>` to start viewing from the tip of the given branch, and `git checkout <branch-name>` to get back "on" the branch (re-attach your HEAD).  Meanwhile, see https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job -

```
git reset HEAD~1
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 case:

**Case 1.** You haven't push the changing to server

```
git reset
```

**Case 2.** You have been pushed the changing to server

```
git revert HEAD
git push
```